# MySQL FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, search, join

I got a MySQL join problem I'm trying to figure for the past few hours.
I have 2 tables:

```
article : 
id(int) 
label(varchar) 
direct_url(varchar)

article_category: 
id(int) 
label(varchar)
```

I'm trying to make a search query using label and joining both tables. I'm doing this:

```
SELECT label,direct_url FROM article FULL OUTER JOIN article_category ON article.label WHERE label LIKE %$q% ORDER BY label ASC
```

This is obviously wrong because it doesn't work. I get 0 results every time regardless of the search key ($q).
I would appreciate if somebody would shad some light into my problem.

Edit: [my source is here.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: ON article.label "= article_category_label" , I think you need to add part in quotes

Comment: @johnyTee: thanks for the reply, I've tried with and without...no success..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  What this does is actually alias the `article` table to `FULL`.  There are two syntax errors: the `OUTER JOIN` by itself, and missing quotes around the `LIKE` value.  `JOIN ON article.label` is also not doing what you want it to do, most likely.  It would have to be `JOIN ON article.label = article_category.label`.

I'm pretty sure you don't want a full outer join -- conceptually this would be values in each table that are not in the other, but in fact it seems like you want to be able to search *both* label fields.  If `label` is the column that identifies the category, it would be better to use the article_category id instead of the current `article.label` column.  If that's not the case, then you don't have anything you can join the tables on anyway.

Comment: I've changed it to ID as recommended and it worked. I also got the same result doing 2 queries instead of 1 with JOIN. Thanks alot for pointing it out, it helped me alot!